# JQuery's .next() doesn't seem to work when changing the object the event is bounded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this mark up:

```
<div class="list-group-item participant-main">
   <i class="fa fa-chevron-down" id="chevron-for-div" aria-hidden="true"></i>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-8">
         <h5 class="list-group-item-heading">A title</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 list-group-item-quick-links ">
        <a href="#" />
        <a href="#" />
      </div>
   </div>
</div>

<div class='list-group-item hidden-group-item hide'>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-8">
         <p class="list-group-item-text">
            Some text
         </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
         <p class="list-group-item-text">
            More text
         </p>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Previously, I was using Jquery to unhide/hide `.hidden-group-item` when `.participant-main` was clicked via this code:

```
$('body').on('click', '.member-main, .participant-main', function() {
  if ($(this).next('.hidden-group-item').hasClass('hide')) {
     $('.hidden-group-item').addClass('hide');
     $(this).next('.hidden-group-item').toggleClass('hide');
  }
  else {
     $(this).next('.hidden-group-item').toggleClass('hide');
  }
  $('.hidden-form-item').addClass('hide');
});
```

I'm adding some links to `.participant-main` so I can't bind a click event to the whole div anymore so the new links work in parallel. I've tried then to bind the click event to particular elements inside the div thus I moved the target class to particular elements like this.

```
<div class="list-group-item">
   <i class="fa fa-chevron-down participant-main" id="chevron-for-div" aria-hidden="true"></i>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-8 participant-main">
         <h5 class="list-group-item-heading">A title</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 list-group-item-quick-links ">
        <a href="#" />
        <a href="#" />
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I was hoping it would work but it does not.

I don't understand why is this happening and how to solve. As far as I understand .next() grabs the next element that matches the specified selector.

Comment: You changed your html code, have you changed your javascript? bc now, .hidden-group-item is not a sibling of .participant-main, as before...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've nested elements you should use `stopPropagation()` to stop the event from bubbling :

```
$('body').on('click', '.member-main, .participant-main', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();

    ...
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Zakaria thanks, I've tried your approach but it didn't work as expected. 
Those links in `participant-main` are generated with ruby-on-rails helper method so after I add  `stopPropagation` I'm indeed able to click those links in parallel to their parent div. However, it messed up with those helpers and their underlying js. They are supposed to be do POST calls and no they are doing GET. I wonder if there's simply a way to link elements within the div to the click event.

Comment: Hi @Andrew the example here should work indeed try to reproduce the issue in the fiddle or snippet so we could helps..